# Flask - Route to another page from a non-view function

Tags: python, flask, routes, jinja2

I have a python code (flights.py) which servers as the backend for flights.html. It has a function called add_flight() which is a used to add a flight to the mongodb database.

flights.py:

```
@flights_bp.route("/search-flights", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def search_flights():
return render_template("flights.html", flights_list = flights_list)

@flights_bp.route("/add-flight", methods=['POST'])
def add_flight():
if True:
    # redirect to payments.html
    return redirect(url_for("payment.payment", to_be_added_flight = to_be_added_flight))
else:
    print(error)
```

payment.py:

```
@payment_bp.route("/payment")
def payment():
    return render_template("payment.html")
```

Is there a way to redirect to the payment() function ins payment.py from the add_flight() function?

In the True block of add_flight(), I tried putting this return value:

```
return redirect(url_for("payment.payment", _external=True))
```

I am able to redirect to payment.html, but I am being shown this:

`The requested URL was not found on the server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.`